# Subaru MY2008 WRX Turbo

Tags: subaru, turbocharger, wrx

I have a 2008 WRX with the stock TD04 turbo.

I cannot hear any spool up as one would usually expect with a turbocharged vehicle.

Yet i have used an ODBII bluetooth device and torque for android to confirm that ECU see's a change in vacuum / boost.

Is this normal or is there likely a problem.

Comment: Hmm just found this which suggests it might be normal, http://www.clubwrx.net/forums/engine-modifications/134286455-trying-get-turbo-spool-sound.html, Would still like an answer from someone who knows their stuff.

Comment: Were you able to hear it spool up before, and now you can't? Or is this just something you noticed compared to other cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've owned three different turbocharged Imprezas and can confirm that it's perfectly normal not to hear the turbo spooling up. In fact on a standard WRX if you *can* hear the turbo spooling that would normally indicate a problem!

If the Torque app is showing the right level of boost then you've got nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any lag getting boost - if not then the turbo is already up to speed. Designs have changed from the early ones and market forces forced a move away from the boy-racer image requiring the power without the noise....

Answer (score 0):

My 2006 Jeep Liberty CRD with the factory Garrett turbo is not audible until it hits about 10 inches, and my hearing is tested to be acute.